# TypeError: Cannot call method 'each' of null - Javascript Type error in Joomla ChronoForms

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, joomla

I'm trying to make a "double" drop down with Joomla ChronoForms but I'm having a Javascript error on the page when I select something from the first dropdown, here is my code:

```
<select id="recipe" name="recipe">
    <optgroup label="test" id="ch_1">
        <option value="blabla">something here</option>
        <option value="blabla">something here</option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="test244" id="ch_2">
        <option value="blabla">something here</option>
        <option value="blabla">something here</option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="testtt" id="ch_3">
        <option value="blabla">something here</option>
        <option value="blabla">something here</option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="testt23521" id="ch_4">
        <option value="blabla">something here</option>
        <option value="blabla">something here</option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="teeesstt" id="ch_5">
        <option value="blabla">something here</option>
        <option value="blabla">something here</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

and the JS code is:

```
window.addEvent('load', function() {
    var num_groups = 5;
    var groups = new Array;

    for ( var i = 1; i <= num_groups; i++ ) {
        groups[i] = $('ch_'+i);
        $('ch_'+i).remove();
    }
    $('chapter').value = '';

    $('chapter').addEvent('change', function() {
        var group_no = $('chapter').value;
        if ( !group_no ) {
            return;
        }

        $('#recipe optgroup').each(function(el) {el.remove()});
        $('recipe').appendChild(groups[group_no]);
    });
});
```

And the JS error that I receive is: **TypeError: Cannot call method 'each' of null**

Could you PLEASE help me with this?
Thank you

Here is the thread in the forum related to this [link](http://www.chronoengine.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=21267&p=303456#p303456) or [link2](http://greyhead.net/chronoforms/creating-a-double-drop-down) , maybe it can help someone find the issue, I've tried everything I can .. :( please someone

Comment: what is this `$('chapter')`, guess it is MooTools, so this kind of selector is short for id selector http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window:dollar, and than if I am right this one `$('#recipe optgroup').each(function(el) {el.remove()});` has to has two dollar syntax http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window:dollars

Comment: WOW, this really solved the issue, I've putted double dollar to the "$('#recipe optgroup').each" and it WORKED !!! Thank you so much

Comment: yep, did not work with MooTools for ages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay, if it is joomla most likely it is MooTools, not sure what version though, try to change selector

> $('#recipe optgroup').each(function(el) {el.remove()});

to

> $$('#recipe optgroup').each(function(el) {el.remove()});

Answer (score 1):

```
$('chapter')
```

If it's not an element it is supposed to be

`$('#chapter') ID` OR  `$('.chapter') Class`

`$('recipe')`  supposed to be `$('#recipe')`

Also if you think this line is **jQuery**

```
$('chapter').addEvent('change', function() {
```

it is supposed to be

```
 $('#chapter').on('change', function() {
```

I never heard of `.addEvent` in javascript

Supposed to be either `attachEvent`  or `eventListener` in vanilla javascript

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `$('#recipe').find('optgroup').each`
 Аre you sure that at the time of each method calling the combobox already created in dom? Try to using setTimeout function

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#recipe').find('optgroup').each.....
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, now the error says : TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of null :(

Comment: I changed my answer. You can change delay for experiment.